# string reversal function using reversed indexing

Tags: python

Could someone please help me understand why the following function does not print out the reverse of the string? What am I doing wrong?

```
def myReverse(data):
    for index in range( len(data)-1, -1, -1 ):
        return data[index]
        print( data[index] )

myReverse('blahblah')
```

Comment: `return` **exits the function** there and then; you are returning just the last element at that point. the `print()`  is never reached.

Comment: You're returning in the first loop. It never reaches the print function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I see . .  Thank you.  I used ` yield ` as well, but that does not work either.  I removed both and left only the ` print ` statement. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a `return` call within the function, the control comes back to parent (which executed the function) ignoring the code within the scope of function after `return`. In your case, that is why `print` is not getting executed by your code.

Move the line containing `print` before `return` and move `return` to outside of the `for` loop. Your code should work then.

**Suggestion:**
There is simpler way to reverse the string using `::-1`. For example:

```
>>> my_string = 'HELLO'
>>> my_string[::-1]
'OLLEH'
```

Comment: Many thanks. I understand what's going on now... Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning before print. So the line `print( data[index] )` is never get executed.

Below code wil work just fine.

```
def myReverse(data):
    for index in range( len(data)-1, -1, -1 ):
        print( data[index] , end = '')
```

Notice that this is a python3 solution. `print` in Python2 doesn't work like that.

So, get the same effect in python2 , first import the `print` from `__future__`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

And then, same as above.

Answer (score 0):

*Intro:* the execution of a `for` loop will stop once a `return` statement or `break` statement is encountered or there is an exception.

You have a `return` statement which makes the `for` loop stop (*returning* control to the caller) as soon as the statement is encountered in the first iteration.

Move the `return` statement outside the `for` loop

Comment: Got it. Cheers!